# convention on exterior derivatives

Tags: differential-forms, convention, de-rham-cohomology

What is the convention on exterior derivatives especially concerning $H^0_{dR}(M)$?

Indeed, $H^0_{dR}(M) = Z^0(M)/B^0(M)$ where $B^0(M) = \Omega^0(M)\cap \text{Im}(d)$. However $d$ is not defined on $\Omega^{-1}(M)$ because $\Omega^{-1}(M)$ is not defined.

Comment: Take $\Omega^{-1}(M)$ as $\{0\}$.

Comment: and so Im(d) = 0 and $B^0(M) = 0$ so $H^0_{dR}(M) = Z^0(M)$